# string to tuple conversion in python

Tags: python, string, tuples

I have a string like this, after reading from a text file line:

```
To = "'abc@hcl.com','xyz@hcl.com','accc@infy.com','satya@lab.com','ach@lab.com'"
```

I want to convert it to a tuple. What I am doing is:

```
To = (To,)
type(To)  #o/p tuple
len(To)   #1
To
("'abc@hcl.com','xyz@hcl.com','accc@infy.com', 'sat@lab.com','ach@lab.com'",)   # output tuple
```

Expected is I need to split each value by `,` and store it to a tuple from string or after tuple conversion:

```
To
('abc@hcl.com','xyz@hcl.com','accc@infy.com', 'sat@lab.com','ach@lab.com',)  # output tuple
len(To)   #should give 5
```

Comment: I answered exactly that for you in the linked duplicate you asked a few hours ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Abstract Syntax Trees](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) as below-

```
>>>import ast
>>>To=ast.literal_eval(To)
>>>print To
>>>('abc@hcl.com', 'xyz@hcl.com', 'accc@infy.com', 'satya@lab.com', 'ach@lab.com')
>>>len(To) 
>>>5
```

Comment: did not know about this dude, really cool, another trick in the hat! thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Or if you don't want to use ast, you can simply run:

```
tuple(word[1:-1] for word in To.split(","))
```

Comment: simplest way till now.

Answer (score 2):

**Notes:**

- you can convert your `String` into `List` by splitting at `,`
- you can then convert the `List` into `Tuple`

**Code:**

```
To = "'abc@hcl.com','xyz@hcl.com','accc@infy.com','satya@lab.com','ach@lab.com'"
print tuple(To.split(","))
```

**Output:**

```
("'abc@hcl.com'", "'xyz@hcl.com'", "'accc@infy.com'", "'satya@lab.com'", "'ach@lab.com'")
```

If you want to remove the `'` quotes

**Code1:**

```
print tuple(elem.strip("'") for elem in To.split(","))
```

**Output1:**

```
('abc@hcl.com', 'xyz@hcl.com', 'accc@infy.com', 'satya@lab.com', 'ach@lab.com')
```

Comment: Thanks Vignesh for the elaborated answer.